# Best practices method of implementing a django OR query from an iterable?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am implementing a one off data importer where I need to search for existing slugs. The slugs are in an array. What is the accepted best practices way of converting an array to an `OR` query?

I came up with the following, which works, but feels like way too much code to accomplish something this simple.

```
# slug might be an array or just a string
# ex:
slug = [ "snakes", "snake-s" ] # in the real world this is generated from directory structure on disk

# build the query
query = MyModel.objects
if hasattr(slug, "__iter__"):
    q = Q()
    for s in slug:
        q = q.__or__(Q(slug=s))
    query = query.filter(q)
else:
    query = query.filter(slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
slug = ["snakes", "snake-s" ] # in the real world this is generated from directory structure on disk

# build the query
query = MyModel.objects
if hasattr(slug, "__iter__"):
    q_list = []
    for s in slug:
        q_list.append(Q(slug=s))
    query = query.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
else:
    query = query.filter(slug=slug)
```

- `q_list = []` create a list of Q clauses
- `reduce(operator.or_, q_list)` implode the list with or operators

read this: http://www.michelepasin.org/techblog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/

@MostafaR - sure we could crush my entire codeblock down to one line if we wanted (see below). Its not very readable anymore at that level though. saying code isn't "Pythonic" just because it hadn't become reduced and obsfucated is silly. Readable code is king IMHO. Its also important to keep in mind the purpose of my answer was to show the `reduce` by an operator technique. The rest of my answer was fluff to show that technique in context to the original question.

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(slug=s) for s in slug])) if hasattr(slug, "__iter__") else MyModel.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

Comment: You can write this more pythonic, like using a generator statement instead of three lines of code to create q_list.

Comment: Pythonic code is not a code with least lines of code, and your one line code is not enough readable. But I'm sure `q_list = [Q(slug=s) for s in slug)]` is more readble than the `for` statement in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = MyModel.objects.filter(slug__in=slug).all() if isinstance(slug, list) else MyModel.objects.filter(slug=slug).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you should use django's [`__in` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#in) like this:

```
slugs = [ "snakes", "snake-s" ]
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(slug__in=slugs)
```

Comment: This solution's problem is same with schacki's solution.

Comment: I know, but schacki was four minutes late :)

Comment: oh, it was in my head immediately, your are just a faster typer than I am :-)

Answer (score -1):

The code that you posted will not work in many ways (but I am not sure if it should be more pseudocode?), but from what I understand, this might help:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(slug__in=slug)
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why but I completed skipped over __in on the docs page.

Comment: This answer is buggy, look at this example: `'test' in 'xxtestxx'` returns `True`. So It seems this solution works but actually it will cause some bugs. The `in` operator works in different ways for `str` and `list`.

Comment: @MostafaR yep, just found that. Thanks.

Comment: Based on the question, slug is an array, not a string, so it exactly does,what it was supposed to, but agree, all() is not necessary.